# How do I fix the ".class expected" error in my code here?

Tags: java

Learning Java, so my code is probably a mess.

Pretty sure I'm declaring the latter variables wrong, and learning to declare them properly will un-knot this mess.

It shows up whenever I get into the methods after the class declarations, and I start to define the "get/set" methods

It's a lab for a pet stay check-in/out system.  We have the pet superclass, and the cat/dog classes.  There's variables for the name, weight, grooming, space number, and so on for dogs whereas the cat just has the space number.  For the dog, the days stay is taken into consideration because if they're staying for 3 or more days, they have the option for grooming.  So, when we check in the dog, all these variables are part of the process, and the amount due is totaled:

```
//Pet Superclass

public class Pet {
    
    // Instance Variables
    
    private String petType;
    private String petName;
    private int petAge;
    private int dogSpaces;
    private int catSpaces;
    private int daysStay;
    private int amountDue;
    
    public Pet(String petType, String petName, int petAge, int dogSpaces, int catSpaces, int daysStay, double amountDue) {
        this.petType = String type;
        this.petName = String name;
        this.petAge = int age;
        this.dogSpaces = int _dogSpaces;
        this.catSpaces = int _catSpaces;
        this.daysStay = int _daysStay;
        this.amountDue = double amtDue;
    }
            
    // get/set PetType
    public String getPetType() {return type;}
    public void setPetType(String _type) {
        this.type = _type;
    }
    
    // get/set PetName
    public String getPetName() {return name;}
    public void setPetName(String _name) {
        this.name = _name;
    }
    
    // get/set PetAge
    public int getPetAge() {return age;}
    public void setPetAge(int _age) {
        this.age = _age;
    }
    
    // get/set DogSpaces
    public int getDogSpaces() {return _dogSpaces;}
    public void setDogSpaces (int dog_Spaces) {
        this._dogspaces = dog_Spaces;
    }
    
    // get/set CatSpaces
    public int getCatSpaces() {return _catSpaces;}
    public void setCatSpaces(int cat_Spaces) {
        this._catSpaces = cat_Spaces;
    }
    
    // get/set DaysStay
    public int getDaysStay() {return _daysStay;}
    public void setDaysStay(int days_stay) {
        this._daysStay = days_stay;
    }
    
    // get/set AmountDue
    public double getAmountDue() {return amtDue;}
    public void setAmountDue(double _amtDue) {
        this.amtDue = _amtDue;
    }
    
// Constructor Declaration Dog Class

    class Dog extends Pet {
        private int dogSpaceNumber;
        private double dogWeight;
        private String grooming;
    
        public Dog(int dogSpaceNumber, double dogWeight, String grooming) {
            this.dogSpaceNumber = int dogSpaceNo;
            this.dogWeight = double _dogWeight;
            this.grooming = String _grooming;
            
        }
        
        // get/set DogSpaceNumber
        public int getDogSpaceNumber() {return dogSpaceNo;}
        public void setDogSpaceNumber(int _dogSpaceNo) {
            this.dogSpaceNo = _dogSpaceNo;
        }
        
        // get/set DogWeight
        public int getDogWeight() {return _dogWeight;}
        public void setDogWeight(double dog_Weight) {
            this._dogWeight = dog_Weight;
        }
        
        // get/set Grooming
        public string getGrooming() {return _grooming;}
        public void setGrooming(String _Grooming) {
            this._grooming = _Grooming;
        }
            
    }

// Constructor Declaration Cat Class

    class Cat extends Pet {
        private int catSpaceNumber;
    
        public Cat(int catSpaceNumber) {
            this.catSpaceNumber = int catSpaceNo;
        }
    
    
    // get/set CatSpaceNumber
        public int getCatSpaceNumber() {return catSpaceNo;}
        public void setCatSpaceNumber(int _catSpaceNo) {
            this.catSpaceNo = _catSpaceNo;
        }
    }
 }
```

I had a few errors before, an extra curly bracket that was out of place as well as a couple more that were messing up the encapsulation that java likes, as well as some typographical errors that were screwing with variable recognition, but this seems to be the last one, and I think it's because I'm not declaring them properly, but googling the problem hasn't exactly given me an "a-ha" realization.

What am I missing?

I am getting `error: .class expected.` whereever I am trying to assign `String`s (`this.variable =` ) and a  `; expected/not statement` error whenever assigning ints.

Comment: `this.catSpaceNumber = int catSpaceNo;` should be `this.catSpaceNumber = catSpaceNo;`

Comment: `this.name = _name;` as an aside, your `Pet` class doesn't have a `name` member.

Comment: In general I would recommend that when beginning to learn java to start small. Create a single small class with 1 or 2 attributes, then run and test that code and if it works keep adding more and more stuff. And work your way up like that, always adding and testing small parts of your code. Simply writing a few classes worth of code without testing and then only trying to compile it all at the end is a recipe for disaster for beginners as your errors will keep piling up.

Comment: As @OHGODSPIDERS says, start with much smaller, simpler tasks until you have a basic level of comfort with the language.

Comment: petName wouldn't be the name member?